# How to make a user automatically from a class in OpenERP?

Tags: python, odoo

Please I want to create a class and combine the firstname and lastname in fullname to make a user by this fullname.

Comment: could you explain it better? Maybe you are looking for the `name_get` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used an onchange function like this
I hope it may help you.

**In python:**

```
def onchange_fullname(self, cr, uid, ids, fname, lname, context=None):

    fullname = '%s %s' % (fname,lname)
    # It will add fname(First Name) and lname(Last Name) and assign to  fullname
    return {'value':{'fullname':fullname}}
```

**In XML:**

```
<field name="name" />
<field name="lname" on_change="onchange_fullname(fname,lname)" />
<field name="fullname" />
```

After you entered the `lname`(last name), when you press tab.
It'll automatically fill the field `fullname`.

Comment: Hello Tintu, thanks for ur answer, this idea gonna resolve my problem, but  I got that error                                                                                            TypeError: onchange_fullname() takes at least 7 arguments (6 given)

Comment: Oh sorry! remove `arg` in that arguments. I have edited and corrected it, please check the updated answer.

Comment: now a new error is:  UnboundLocalError: local variable 'fullname' referenced before assignment

Comment: Actually, I wrote a normal function definition and answered you. Sorry for that. Now I have updated the answer for onchange and It will work perfectly. Try this for sure.

Answer (score 1):

yes I did this is how look like my code

```
def onchange_fullname(self, cr, uid, ids, fname, lname, context=None):
    value = {}
    fullname=""
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        fullname = '%s %s' % (record.fname or '', record.lname or '')
    # It will add fname(First Name) and lname(Last Name)
    return {value:{'name':fullname}}

_name = 'parent.parent'
_table = "parent_parent"
_description = 'Parent Information'
_inherits = {'res.users': 'user_id'}

_columns = {

    'user_id': fields.many2one('res.users', 'User ID', ondelete="cascade", select=True, required=True),
    'parent_name':fields.related('user_id', 'name', type='char', relation='parent.parent', string='Full Name'),
    'fname': fields.char('First name', size=64),
    'lname': fields.char('Last name', size=64),
    'address_ids' : fields.one2many('res.partner', 'parent_id', 'Contacts'),
    'fonction': fields.char('Fonction',size=64,required="True"),
    'parent_id': fields.many2one('parent.parent', 'name'),
    'street': fields.char('Street', size=128, required=True,),
    'zip': fields.char('Zip', change_default=True, size=24, required=True,),
    'city': fields.char('City', size=128,),
    'state_id': fields.many2one("res.country.state", 'State', required=True,),       
    'country_id': fields.many2one('res.country', 'Country', required=True,),
    'contact_phone':fields.related('parent_id', 'phone', type='char', relation='parent.parent', string='Téléphone Fixe', required=True,),
    'contact_mobile':fields.related('parent_id', 'mobile', type='char', relation='parent.parent', string='Téléphone mobile', required=True,),
    'contact_email':fields.related('parent_id', 'user_email', type='char', relation='parent.parent', string='Email', required=True,),}
```

Comment: def onchange_fullname(self, cr, uid, ids, fname, lname, context=None):
        fullname = '%s %s' % (fname or '', lname or '')
        # It will add fname(First Name) and lname(Last Name)
        return {'value':{'name':fullname}}

Comment: See my previous answer itself. It'll help you. I have updated it with corrections.

Comment: If my answer helps you, support me by upvote my answer. Thank you. :)